# Amazon AWS: FIFO SQS, What is considered a transaction?

Tags: amazon-web-services, transactions, amazon-sqs, fifo

As you may know, Amazon SQS FIFO queue are limited to 300 TPS/s (Transactions per second). What is considered a transaction? The basic usage of a FIFO is the following:

1. send message
2. read message
3. delete message

Is every action considered a transaction or only send? or only send+read but not delete? I haven't found anything about it in the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the AWS Documentation:

> Message throughput:
>
> Without batching, FIFO queues can support up to 300 messages per second (300 send, receive, or delete operations per second).
>
> If you take advantage of the maximum batching of 10 messages per operation, FIFO queues can support up to 3,000 messages per second.

Doc: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/limits-messages.html

Comment: What happens if the limit is crossed? Does the operation fail?

Comment: @AndyDufresne the operation will fail.